# What is a difference between `mtime` and modification time in gsutil rsync documentation?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

The [gsutil rsync documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) describes two options which sound identical:

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| -i | This forces rsync to skip any files which exist on the destination and have a modified time that is newer than the source file. (If an existing destination file has a modification time equal to the source file's, it will be updated if the sizes are different.) |
| -u | When a file/object is present in both the source and destination, if mtime is available for both, do not perform the copy if the destination mtime is newer. |

Although they use different terms, mtime and modification time, still it seems to be the same. At least I have not found any info on the difference. Both options effectively state that the file will not be copied (skipped) if the destination file is newer.

However, there must be some difference. I can't assume that the product team kept two identical options by mistake.

**What is the difference between `mtime` and `modification time` particularly in the context of the `gsutil rsync` command? And, consequently, what is the difference in effect of these two options?**

The only possible difference may be in the case of equal modification times of the source and destination, as described in the parentheses. In this case, the documentation might be improved to explicitly link the two options and point out the only difference. At least the same terms should be used to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage objects do not have a modified time. Objects are immutable.

The word **mtime** is the variable name that holds the file's (or another object type) last modification time. This came from the Unix operating system. Different operating systems have different timestamp precision, for example, the original DOS operating system timestamp precision was two seconds. Unix was one second. Many Linux variants also use one second. NTFS uses nanoseconds but that precision is limited to the clock hardware.

The term **modification time** means the time an object was last modified. It is typically expressed using strings that humans can read, for example, ISO 8601 YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-TZ.

The last modified time is stored in the variable named **mtime** in most Unix-derived operating systems and many others and is a binary number. **mtime** starts at 1970 for most operating systems except for Windows.

They are for all practical purposes the same thing - one is a term and the other a variable name. They are often used interchangeably.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Now I realize that the question within the post body is not specific enough, yet in the title it is specific: what is the difference between the two particularly in the `gsutil rsync` command. Not theoretical, but practical: how these two options differ from each other. I will edit the question now.

Comment: @AKd - In regards to **rsync** it does not matter which wording you want to use. They are for all practical purposes the same. Rsync will compare two dates (call it modification time or mtime) and make a decision that the objects are the same based upon the date calculated from those numbers. The documentation should not use the word **mtime** as that is a variable name and not a value.

Comment: Then why two options that seem to do the same?

Comment: @AKd They do the same thing. Some systems do not have mtime. Notice the wording **if mtime is available for both**, The first option will try to calculate the last modified time, the second option will only take effect if mtime exists on the source and destination.

Comment: This reading a bit contradicts the [Change Detection Algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#change-detection-algorithm) section of the documentation, where it is stated that, “gsutil rsync first checks whether the file modification time (mtime) of both the source and destination is available”. See, these two terms are used as **synonyms**. Nowhere it is described that `gsutil` makes any distinction between them. What is the basis of your statement from the previous comment?

Comment: @AKd - I do not understand what point you are making or what the question is. My basic for my answer is I worked on the design of several operating systems, a number of file systems, and tools like `gsutil`.

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness of thought, English is not my mother tongue. My question is “what is the difference in effect of these two options?”, which you addressed in the comment above. My points are that (1) this explanation contradicts the documentation as I mentioned above, and (2) it is not clear whether it is just your guess or you know this for sure as a developer of `gsutil` or from the developers of it. Regards.

Comment: @AKd - My answer is detailed. The source code to `gsutil` is published. Look at the source and decide for yourself.